# Is it possible with firebase to create a user based on phone data or another form, avoiding sign ups on app to authenticate?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Swift iOS app which I want to avoid the process of creating a login/signup authentication for user. But still allowing individual users to able to save certain content of the app. Therefore improvising a form of unique id in Firebase, to retrieve all saved info saved only for that phone/user.

How would this be possible only using Realtime Database Firebase?

Comment: You can put whatever data you want in Realtime Database - your own generated IDs, if you want.  I don't really understand the problem you're running into here.

Comment: How to always have that unique id linked to that phone. No matter if the app is closed and open again.

Comment: Save it to local storage?

Comment: That would involve using plist or core data, I was look for a way to only depend on firebase. If there isn't then yes I would use a local storage

Comment: What about if the user change device?

Comment: Download the app again and redo saving of info. The idea is to purposely not save anything related to users information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd typically use [anonymous sign in on Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth) for that. This generates a unique ID the first time you call `Auth.auth().signInAnonymously()`, and then uses that to identify the app instance. You could use that to key the data you store for that user in the database.

Comment: even if the user closes the app/restarts phone, would it maintain the same id and still be able to get info for that specific user?

Comment: Yep, the anonymous user's UID is persisted to disk, so restored between sessions. It is wiped is when the user uninstalls the app, or when you sign them out.

Answer (score 0):

Realtime Database doesn't have a concept of per-user or per-device storage.  You need to generate your own unique IDs in order to effectively partition off a space for each user or device.  The database will not do that for you.